# Cant unscribe firebase cloud messaging android

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Sorry for my english. I try use FCM for my test application, everething work fine i use documentation, and in this documentation write if you want unsubscribe from topik use `unsubscribeFromTopic`, and i use it like this:

```
 public void unscribeChannel(final String chanel) {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("/topics/topik" + chanel);
}
```

but after this nothink happens, I still get notifications( 
Then i try delete token like this:

```
  FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteToken(getToken(), "/topics/topik" + chanel);
```

but i think it not good and it not help me too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write the topic without slashes, like this :

`FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("topic_name_only_no_slashes");`

## Example :

[image: Example Image]

## Update:

You can get list of topics of a user using this:

### HTTP GET Request

```
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/<TOKEN>?details=true
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
```

Comment: thanks a lot! It is necessary to carefully read the documentation))

Comment: Can you chack this, i clearly understand or not. I subscribe like this:  `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("user2")` and unscribe `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("user2");` but push i still get notifications(

Comment: Yes, its tested. It works fine. Check my updated ansers.

Comment: I did FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("user2"); and still get data. Is there a way to manually stop the service?